# How to capture output in a file from php artisan test?

Tags: php, laravel, shell

When I run `php artisan test`, I want to save all the output test generates in a file. I tried doing `php artisan test 2> te.txt 1> to.txt`. But the files are empty. What am I doing wrong?

I also tried `php artisan test | tee test.txt` or `php artisan test > test.txt`. Both of them doesn't work.

https://youtu.be/pqNfMDqwixs

Comment: Personally I make use of [PHPUnit extensions](https://phpunit-document-english.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extending-phpunit.html#) for logging/reporting purposes. `php artisan test --without-tty` *might* work for your case as well but not sure

Comment: @apokryfos That works, thanks. But where did you find that flag? Where is it documented?

Comment: It's not actually documented in the docs but you can see it if you do `php artisan help test`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For it to work,

you need the without-tty option :

```
php artisan test --without-tty > test.txt
```

but be aware that it will be filled with color codes, like :

```
[31;1m⨯[39;22m[39m [2m myTest [22m[39m
```

so to display it correctly you will need to cat the file

Comment: This doesn't work: https://youtu.be/pqNfMDqwixs

Comment: try with phpunit directly instead of php artisan test then, i guess the artisan does something weird

Comment: the without-tty option was missing that why output was empty

Comment: Yes as apokryfos said.

Comment: You are right i did not saw that comment

Answer (score 1):

you can use this syntax to fill the file with console output

```
php artisan test >> test.txt
```